# Null validation for getting property values using reflection

Tags: c#, .net, linq, reflection

Here i am trying to add a generic list of values to a dictionary.

Below is the DocDetails class

```
public class DocDetails
{
   public string DocId { get; set; }
   public string Description { get; set; }
   public string Category { get; set; }
}
```

Iam getting a list of `DocDetails` in `docDetailsList` object. Using this am getting each item of DocDetails and getting the property name and value and then adding to a Dictionary.

```
Dictionary<string, List<object>> docDict = new Dictionary<string, List<object>>();

  foreach (var doc in docDetailsList)
     {
          var dict = doc.GetType().GetProperties().ToDictionary(
            m => m.Name, m => new List<object>()
             {
                m.GetValue(doc, null).ToString()
             });
         docDict.Add(dict);
      }
```

When trying to get property value in this line `m.GetValue(doc, null).ToString()` getting exception if the value is null.
How can i validate that , even if its null i need to add that property name to the list with an empty value. Can any one help me out here please

Comment: If you use C# >= 6, you can use null-conditional operator: `m.GetValue(doc, null)?.ToString()`, for older versions use a temporary variable and a ternary conditional operator.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
m.GetValue(doc, null).ToString()
```

You can check, if it's null before calling `ToString()`:

```
m.GetValue(doc, null) != null ? m.GetValue(doc, null).ToString() : null
```